# spyder 3 color calibration with 17.10

Tags: color-management, gnome-color-manager, icc

With Ubuntu 17.10 (artful aardvark):

when trying to calibrate my monitor with my datacolor spyder 3 calibration tool using the settings - devices - color manager, after I am told to hang the instrument on the screen and start calibrating I get something like

> an internal error occurred that could not be recovered - remove
>   calibration device

does anbybody know what to do here? Thanks.
minyves

EDIT:

Found it! It worked after

```
apt-get install colord-sensor-argyll
```

Comment: It would be better if you answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked in Ubuntu 17.10 after running this command:

```
sudo apt install colord-sensor-argyll
```

Comment: And with 18.04 it's the same...

Answer (score 2):

Try using DisplayCAL/dispcalGUI. It should install necessary components and the interface is pretty much straight forward. Side note: it takes a while to calibrate, so best make a cup of tea/coffee and turn off monitor saving for the calibration process.

To install dispcalGUI in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install dispcalgui colord # colord is an optional package
```

Comment: dispcalGUI finishes calibrating and asks if the generated profile should be installed. I say yes and get a message that profile icc-123456-very-long-number can't be found. I too can't find a profile with that name anywhere on my disk.
The gnome-color-thing from gnome-settings works perfectly, though.

Comment: Worked in Ubuntu 18.4.3 with Spyder 5. For orientation, try this link https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Monitor_profilieren_mit_ArgyllCMS/

Comment: Just to clarify, `dispcalgui` is a graphical interface for Argyll. It is not available for systems after Bionic. I don't know why. https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/graphics/dispcalgui

Comment: For some time now (at least with 22.04) dispcalgui is gone from the official repo. It can be installed as the displaycal flatpak as mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338986/problem-installing-displaycalgui