# Problem installing displaycalgui

Tags: dpkg

I get the following errors when trying to install displaycal gui

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of displaycal:
 displaycal depends on python (<< 2.8); however:
  Package python is not installed.
 displaycal depends on python (>= 2.7~); however:
  Package python is not installed.
 displaycal depends on python:any (<< 2.8).
 displaycal depends on python:any (>= 2.7~).
 displaycal depends on python-wxgtk3.0 (>= 3.0) | python-wxgtk2.8 (>= 2.8.11); however:
  Package python-wxgtk3.0 is not installed.
  Package python-wxgtk2.8 is not installed.
 displaycal depends on python-numpy (>= 1.0); however:
  Package python-numpy is not installed.
 displaycal depends on python-psutil; however:
  Package python-psutil is not installed.
 displaycal depends on python-gi; however:
  Package python-gi is not installed.
 displaycal depends on libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0; however:
  Package libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 is not installed.
```

Python is installed and at: /usr/bin/python
Python version is Python 3.9.4

It says it can be 2 or over 2.8 from what the error says.
Ubuntu 21.04 on intel macbook pro

```
 sudo apt-get install -f
```

Above command does not fix. I thought Anaconda may be causing the issue as it was at a different path so I uninstalled but it did not fix it

Program source: https://displaycal.net/, they have a 19.04 version but nothing after

Thanks

Comment: What is the source of displaycal? Please share a link. I don not see any in [official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=displaycal).

Comment: https://displaycal.net/, good point, it supports ubuntu up to 19 officially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual installation of dependencies is difficult and long process.

So I would recommend to install the DisplayCAL application using Flatpak:

```
sudo apt-get install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo

flatpak install flathub net.displaycal.DisplayCAL
```

Comment: flatpack brings in duplicate software for GLat this writing this is some 400MB of GL-related packages (nvidia drivers included).

Answer (score 0):

DisplayCal 3.8.9.3 was released on 2019-12-14, when python2 was alive and well.  Now python2 is deprecated and many python2 packages are no longer available from the package repositories.  That is the underlying reason for the missing dependencies.

The easiest way to use DisplayCal is to use the Flatpak version, as described in another answer:

```
flatpak install flathub net.displaycal.DisplayCAL
```

DisplayCal has also been [updated for python3](https://github.com/eoyilmaz/displaycal-py3).  This new version may eventually make it to Linux software repositories.  Until then, it is available from PyPI:

```
sudo apt install python3-dev python3-xlib libx11-dev libxxf86vm-dev \
   libxext-dev libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev
 
pip install displaycal
```

Comment: FWIW: The python3 version appears to have some problem(s) with getting wxWindows dependencies installed (on Ubuntu 20.04).